# Getting files from server on AWS Using Jenkins Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on my local machine (on premises). I have my server (Linux) in AWS Cloud. I need to share logs with developers with out  giving server access  to them. I need  to create a jenkins job by running that job they should get the logs from server.

How can i do that ?? If any one following the same process to get the data from cloud please help me in solving this... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [SSH Agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) to securely setup your private key
2. Use SCP to copy the log files to the local workspace
3. Archive those files to the Jenkins job

You could write a [pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) script to do this. Something like:

```
node ("linux") {
  sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'scp user@awshostnamehere:/somepath/somelogfile .'
    archive somelogfile
  }
}
```

Note that this requires you to fill in the blanks. To get this to work you would have to:

1. Setup an SSH private key credential named deploy-dev
2. Setup a build agent with the label 'linux' or change that to a label of an agent you do have.